# In Django, prefilling DateField is not working when setting the widget to DateInput

Tags: django, django-forms

I wish to prefill a form field with a specific date.

I have a CreateView:

```
class CreateEventView(CreateView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'events/form.html'
    form_class = EventForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(CreateEventView, self).get_initial()
        initial['start_date'] = datetime.date(day=2,month=11,year=2018)
        return initial
```

If I use this ModelForm, it displays the prefilled date in a text field (as expected):

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    start_date = DateField()
    # ...
```

But I wish to use a nice date picker widget. But then prefilling does not work any more:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    start_date = DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    # ...
```

Why is that so? What can I do about this? Is this behavior somewhere documented?

Comment: Can you please clarify this code `datetime.date(day=int(day=2,month=11,year=2018))` Shouldn't it be just `datetime.date(day=2,month=11,year=2018)` ?

Comment: You are right. I made an error on simplifying my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a Format to the widget like this:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    start_date = DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%Y-%m-%d', attrs={'type': 'date'}), required=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a problem in Django. HTML data input expects default value in format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Make sure it's rendering with date value in that format. I suspect right now it might be rendering as:

```
<input type='date' name='date' value='22-02-2018'/>
```

But what you want is:

```
<input type='date' name='date' value='2018-02-22'/>
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fkmdzhy/) for a demo.

You need to either format your date value properly in a string on backend or do some js magic after rendering.

Comment: for me `... type="date" value="{{ my_date|date:'Y-n-d' }} />"` worked. When `my_date`is a `models.DateTimeField()`